# Tangents perpendicular to the initial line for cardioid? Polar coordinates...

Tags: derivatives, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

For the polar curve $r=a(1+cos\theta)$, I am trying to find the equations of the tangents perpendicular to the initial line by setting $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ equal to zero. I am able to factorise a sine term out, so one of the solutions I get is that there is at theta=pi.
Problem is that this is also a solution to tangents parallel to the initial line... On the curve, it seems to come in as a peak at this point. Now I am not sure whether it should be treated as tangents parallel or perpendicular to the initial line...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the initial line the line from $O(0,0)$ to $(2a,0)$?

Comment: Apologies for not explaining- we take the initial line as being $\theta=0$

Comment: On calculating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of  $r$ and $\theta$ and equating to $0$,  $\theta =\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{5\pi}{3}, \pi$. $\theta =\pi$ comes as a derivative because of the nature of the curve and the sharp curvature at $\pi$.